# Telegram new source code APP ID issue (CONNECTION_API_ID_INVALID)

Tags: ios, telegram

I'm experiencing issue with *NEW* Telegram iOS app source code.

Short question:

There is always **CONNECTION_API_ID_INVALID** error while I'm trying to connect. Do someone solve such issue?

---

Long question:

I've downloaded theirs *NEW* [source code](https://telegram.org/apps)
So, I did fix assertion's by replacing in **TGTelegraph.mm**:

```
NSAssert(false, @"Please obtain your own apiId and apiHash at https://my.telegam.org");
```

With:

```
_apiId = @"my_api_id"; // Number 
_apiHash = @"my_api_hash"; // Hash string
```

Also I did comment same assert in **TGTelegramNetworking.mm**

```
//NSAssert(false, @"Please obtain your own apiId at https://my.telegam.org");
```

And the result is always an error:

```
[MTRequestMessageService#0x1a3c2770 in response to 6129750297537847296 400: (null):CONNECTION_API_ID_INVALID]
```

---

I've tried:

- Replace api_id and api_hash with another one private (currently working with old code)
- Replace api_id and api_hash with another public api_id and api_hash that was provided by Telegram with old public code.
- Change `MTDatacenterAddress` in **TGTelegramNetworking.mm** to IP provided at https://my.telegram.org/apps
- Change `MTDatacenterAddress` in **TGTelegramNetworking.mm** to IP provided by old source code
- Try different combinations at the list above.

---

I found:

- Changes to `MTDatacenterAddress` in **TGTelegramNetworking.mm**
  applies only after app **reinstallation**
- Public keys stop working in
  old code too.
- Fingerprint of a server being checked successfully
  (last field in [dev console](https://my.telegram.org/apps))

Did someone experience same issue? Can anyone suggest something to try? Actually I ran out of varians to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I finished my search.
Yo need in place of second Assetion input following code in **TGTelegramNetworking.mm**:

```
apiEnvironment.apiId = your_app_id_as_number;
```

I hope this answer will save time for someone, because I spent few days.

Answer (score 0):

I supplement the above answer

TGTelegramNetworking.m is in /Telegraph/Core/Network

Answer (score 0):

I know this is outdated, but if anyone needs it, now they are under

```
/Telegraph/TGTelegraph.mm
```

in the form of

```
getAppPrefs.api_id = id_as_number;
getAppPrefs.api_hash = @"hash_as_string";
```